# Getting runtime properties with ReflectionClass

Tags: php, class, object, properties, access-modifiers

So I am exploring the use of the Reflection class. I noticed a few thing.
Had to set the accessibility of my property before being able to use the value or name of the property **Even** from within the Origin class.

What I would like to know is it possible to get properties set at runtime through the `ReflectionClass`. For example

```
class MyClass
{
    public $bathroom = 'Dirty';
    protected $individual = 'President';
    private $conversation = '****************';

    function outputReflectedPublic()
    {
        $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this);
        $props = $reflection->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
        foreach($props as $prop)
            echo $prop->getName() . ' : ' . $prop->getValue($this);
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->outputReflectedPublic();//bathroom : Dirty
//now we add a new property
$obj->$ect = 'ify';
$obj->outputReflectedPublic();//bathroom : Dirty  //same as before
```

Now I am not too surprised by this. 
I tried to see if the property lied within the instance as a protected/Private/Static with the `ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE` , `ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED` and `ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC`

I also used `$prop->setAccessible(true)` to prevent the inaccessible error.
I was unable to see the `$ect` property.

I was able to get the `$ect` property through an internal function as such:

```
function getAll()
{
    foreach($this as $key=>$val)
        echo $key . ' : ' . $val . '<br>';
}
```

> bathroom : Dirty
>
> individual : President
>
> converstation : ****************
>
> ect : ify

Is there a way to get that(`$ect`) types of properties from an object from the ReflectionClass? and what is the official name for these properties?

Comment: `ReflectionClass` explicitly reflects on the **class**; what you want is to reflect on the object instance, for which `ReflectionObject` is the right reflector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ReflectionClass::getProperties() gets only properties explicitly defined by a class. To reflect all properties you set on an object including dynamic properties, use ReflectionObject which inherits from ReflectionClass and works on runtime instances:

```
$reflect = new ReflectionObject($this);
```

Comment: Oh nice does this still allow the `IS_PUBLIC` filter etc. and is *dynamic properties* the offical  name for runtime set properties?

Comment: As it derives from ReflectionClass it supports all the interfaces that you can use with that class including getProperties with filters.

Comment: Do you knwo if therer is a performance hit when using `ReflectionObject` over `ReflectionClass`? In the case where the object may or may not have extra properties